# Modify global value from a onSuccess call?

Tags: amazon-web-services, typescript, ionic-framework

I am using this function from the [aws Cognito docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html).

```
cognitoUser.forgotPassword({
    onSuccess: function (result) {
        console.log('call result: ' + result);
    },
    onFailure: function(err) {
        alert(err);
    },
    inputVerificationCode() {
        var verificationCode = prompt('Please input verification code ','');
        var newPassword = prompt('Enter new password ' ,'');
        cognitoUser.confirmPassword(verificationCode, newPassword, this);
    }
});
```

Instead of using a prompt, I want to display or not 2 field in HTML so the user can fill them in place of having 2 ugly prompt. All I need to do is replacing the function calling the prompts by a function changing a boolean value.

I tried this: (*for some reason, I had to call `changevalue()` inside the onsuccess or it wouldn't execute*)

```
cognitoconstruct.forgotPassword({
  onSuccess: function (result) {
    console.log('call result: ' + result);
    this.changevalue()
  }, onFailure: function (err) {
    alert(err);
  }, changevalue() {
    console.log('display', this.display)
    this.display = true;
  }
})
```

However, you guessed it: `this.display` being undefined in this function, it doesn't change outside. I can't call any variable or function with `this.xxx`.
How can change this value ?

I tried adding a .then() or change the function to use a legit callback but no luck.

edit: I also tried this: `onSuccess: this.changevalue(),` the boolean do change value but the whole thing crash  soon after `e.onSuccess is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

it seem my brain have a surge of creativity after asking a question here  -_-

I placed the whole function calling forgotPassword() in a promise and used a good old callback to switch the value...

```
recoverPassword() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   let cognitoconstruct = this.user.recover_password(this.forgot_password.value.email);
   cognitoconstruct.forgotPassword({
     onSuccess: function (result) {
       resolve()
     }, onFailure: function (err) {
       alert(err);
       reject();
     }
   })
 })
}
```

```
this.recoverPassword().then(() => this.display = true)
```